# How to work with C++ Windows Runtime Component and AnyCPU target?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I made a *Windows Runtime Component* with VS2013, using C++/CX and targeting Universal Apps. Therefore, I now have 5 DLL files:

- **Windows**

  - **ARM**

    - MyLib.winmd
    - MyLib.dll
  - **x86**

    - MyLib.winmd
    - MyLib.dll
  - **x64**

    - MyLib.winmd
    - MyLib.dll
- **WindowsPhone**

  - **ARM**

    - MyLib.winmd
    - MyLib.dll
  - **x86**

    - MyLib.winmd
    - MyLib.dll

My customer wants to use this library in a Windows 8.1 project. He told me that he cannot use the lib with a project targeting "AnyCPU", which is normal since each DLL is for a single platform. However, what should I tell him? How should he create his project in order to get a package working on each platform?

Comment: He needs to remove the AnyCPU platform from his project, that can't work anymore.  Build + Configuration Manager, upper right combo, Edit.  Select AnyCPU and click Remove.

Comment: True, but how can he add a reference to the lib? He wants to build his app for all architectures, but if the reference to the lib points to its ARM version, the x86 build won't succeed. What is the common way to reference a lib with multiple architectures in it?

Comment: The .winmd file is platform-independent, it just contains type descriptions.  Metadata that the compiler uses to know how to generate the proper platform-specific code to use the types.  Equivalent to, say, a .h file but usable by many different compilers.  Like the C# compiler that your client is using.  You should publish only one.

Answer (score 1):

AnyCPU is not supported for native code, only for pure managed code.

You'll need to distribute the platform specific modules and your customer will need to target specific architectures and include the appropriate version of the component for the target architecture.

One way is to put the component in folders named for the configuration and choose the version to reference by the $configuration property.

An easy way to set this up is to distribute the component as an extension SDK which will set up the appropriate directory structure and include the matching version for the configuration. See [Distributing a managed Windows Runtime component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj614475.aspx) and [How to: Create a Software Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh768146.aspx) on MSDN (the managed doc has a good overview even for native components).

A [nuget package](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) can also achieve the same thing.